# Hundreds of blank pages and/or disproportion when printing a web page, after chrome version ~103 release (solved)

Tags: css, google-chrome, printing

507 pages are being printed even though there are only 9 pages of content (498 blank pages)

[image: 1]

Dearest community, after one of the latest releases of chrome, somewhere after version ~103-105, an unfortunate bug appears when printing a web page.
**It either prints hundreds of blank pages and/or prints distorted proportions outputs.
This change applies to all chromium based browsers (Google Chrome, MS Edge...),
and occurs especially in pages with charts or graphs.**

Comment: Thanks for sharing, I ran into this today and was feeling pretty puzzled.

Comment: Hi dear Matt, glad I could help and thank you very much for the appreciation.

Answer (score 7):

If anyone else encountered this issue - the reason lies in the CSS property "position: absolute".
If your code posseses "position: absolute" you may want to change it to "fixed" or "relative", depending on your needs.
My code needed 2 changes. One required massive refactoring since changing the position property enforced me to recalculate lots of other elements.
The second took only 3 lines of code but alot longer to find since it made me override "Charts.js" internal CSS styling and implemented the "!important" flag, like so (my app uses chartjs version 2.9.4):

```
.chartjs-size-monitor-expand > div {
   position: fixed !important; // cannot stay "absolute"
}
```

The "position: absolute" property appears in 3 other classes, so if the above suggestion does not suffice - you may want to try the following (or locate other places containing absolute position):

```
.chartjs-size-monitor,
.chartjs-size-monitor-shrink,
.chartjs-size-monitor-expand,
.chartjs-size-monitor-expand > div {
   position: fixed !important; // cannot stay "absolute"
}
```

Hope this helps. Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

Same problem here, also using ChartJS. Thanks for posting your solution, it is working for us. Note there is an open [Chromium issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1399313&q=print&can=2) about this.

Comment: Dear rosemcc, thank you very much for the kind words. this is my first ever post on stackoverflow and I'm happy it was helpful for you. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, it printed exactly 420 blank pages more. I just added this to my custom css file:

```css
.chartjs-size-monitor-expand > div {
  position: fixed !important;
}
```