# Is there a way to customize the number of pages being printed on JavaScript / React?

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, printing, chart.js

I am currently working on a React application that uses Chart.js. Recently, I have found a new bug when using Chrome: whenever I'm trying to print a page that contains the charts, over 600 additional blank pages are generated.

This happens whether I print using cmd + print or window.print().

It is important that people can print these reports on our application. This issue is currently happening on Chrome, but not on Safari.

Is there any way to set the number of pages being printed, either with CSS or JavaScript?
maybe some property on @media print ?

Your help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I investigated this issue further.
The v108 Google Chrome update brought issues on Print Preview for many users.

There is a workaround that involves applying this CSS:

```
  .chartjs-size-monitor-expand > div {
    position: fixed !important; // cannot stay “absolute”
  }

  chartjs-size-monitor,
  .chartjs-size-monitor-shrink,
  .chartjs-size-monitor-expand,
  .chartjs-size-monitor-expand > div {
    position: fixed !important; // cannot stay “absolute”
  }
```

Source: [Hundreds of blank pages and/or disproportion when printing a web page, after chrome version ~103 release (solved)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74745255/hundreds-of-blank-pages-and-or-disproportion-when-printing-a-web-page-after-chr)

This fixed my issue! Hope it can help anyone who needs it.